# \DTMsavedate calculation does not work with \DTMusedate

Tags: datetime2

I would like to calculate a new date based on a previous one with `\DTMusedate`, but I got an error from `\@dtm@parsedate`.

Here's a sample :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}

\newcommand{\offset}{30}

\DTMsavedate{foo}{2018-01-15}
\DTMsavedate{bar}{\DTMusedate{foo}+\offset}

\begin{document}

This is the first date : \DTMusedate{foo}
This should be the first date + \offset days : \DTMusedate{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: Hey @Andrew, thanks, I just updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is described in section 9 of the `datetime2` manual, you'll have to convert the date to a julian day and then add the offset:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}

\newcommand{\offset}{30}

\DTMsavedate{foo}{2018-01-15}
\newcount\tmp
\DTMsaveddateoffsettojulianday{foo}{\offset}{\tmp}
\DTMsavejulianday{bar}{\tmp}

\begin{document}
This is the first date: \DTMusedate{foo}

This should be the first date + \offset\ days: \DTMusedate{bar}
\end{document}
```